# add array value in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hello Iam new in Php I have Some Dout in Array
this is my array

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [2] => abc.zip
            [3] => xyz.rar
       )
)
```

I need to add String in Array Values.. Like this

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [2] => domain.com/abc.zip
            [3] => domain.com/xyz.rar
       )
)
```

I want Add Every Values `domain.com/` How his Possible(sorry for bad English)

Comment: [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple loop and concat...

```
foreach($array['files'] as $key=>$value){
  $array['files'][$key] = "domain.com/".$value;
}
```

Comment: You obviously know this, but OP may find it useful that it can be shortened to `"domain.com/$value"` since it's in double quotes.

Comment: Also, this seems like the perfect place to use a reference to update the values instead of using `['files'][$key]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using array_map:

```
<?php
$source = array(
    'files' => array(
        1 => 'abc.zip',
        3 => 'xyz.rar'
   )
);


$prefix = 'domain.com/';

$source['files']  = array_map(
    function ($el) use ($prefix) {
        return  $prefix.$el;
    },
    $source['files']
);

print_r($source);
```

You can try this code [here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=d8447d357c972a100c00d2919f63991d&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)